# QML TabView: Get tabIndex for a specific tab

Tags: qt, qml, tabview

Is there any way to get the index of a specific tab from tabview by using the title or id fields?
Something like: `tabviewComponent.indexOf(redTab)`

```
TabView {
     id: tabviewComponent
     Tab {
        id: redTab
        title: "Red"
     }
     Tab {
         id: blueTab
         title: "Blue"
     }
     Tab {
         id: greenTab
         title: "Green"
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such function by default but you can create that function by iterating:

```
TabView {
    id: tabviewComponent
    Tab {
        id: redTab
        title: "Red"
    }
    Tab {
        id: blueTab
        title: "Blue"
    }
    Tab {
        id: greenTab
        title: "Green"
    }

    function indexOf_by_id(id){
        for(var i=0; i < count; i++){
            if(id === getTab(i))
                return i
        }
        return -1
    }

    function indexOf_by_title(title){
        for(var i=0; i < count; i++){
            if(title === getTab(i).title)
                return i
        }
        return -1
    }
}
```

Use:

```
tabviewComponent.indexOf_by_id(redTab)
tabviewComponent.indexOf_by_title("Green")
```